# Face Recognition and comparative on maui blazor offline

Tags: maui-blazor

i need have a face recognition and comparative on maui blazor offline app because our client needs to take photos of their employees for assit in the field and they dont have access to internet.

we need a quicly comparative and offline, i dont see a examples on maui blazors.

Thanks! :)

an answer and example on maui blazor